# Invalid arguments supplied for foreach - PHP

Tags: php

I want to insert record for each pincode into database but i am getting this error.Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

My code is this.

```
 if(!empty($post_data['pincode'])){
   $explode_pincode = implode(',',$post_data['pincode']);
    $data['pincode'] = $explode_pincode;


         foreach($data['pincode'] as $pinvalue)
           { $post_data['pincode']=$pinvalue;
            $post_data['store_name']=$store_name;
            $post_data['store_id']=$store_id;
            $result = $this->msproduct_model->insertPromo($post_data);
           }
```

Comment: You're imploding on line 2, not exploding.

Comment: `$data['pincode']`  is a string right now because of this:- `$explode_pincode = implode(',',$post_data['pincode']);`  . So you can't apply foreach

Comment: if i use explode it says       explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you just miss typing *explode* to *implode*.

Answer (score 1):

> getting the following error “Warning: Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach() ”

Its because of either `null` or `false` or argument is not array

```
foreach($data['pincode'] as $pinvalue){ 
             ^
            see var_dump($data['pincode']), 
            since $data['pincode'] is either null or false or not array you get above error
```

We can regenerate this error like this for example

```
$ php -r 'foreach(null as $e){}'
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command line code on line 1

/*false OR FALSE*/
$ php -r 'foreach(false as $e){}'
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command line code on line 1

/* Not array */
$ php -r 'foreach("somestring" as $e){}'
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command line code on line 1
```

So you need correct one line first

> implode — Join array elements with a string

**From**

```
$explode_pincode = implode(',',$post_data['pincode']);
```

> explode — Split a string by string

explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX ] )

> Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string
>   formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

**to**

```
$explode_pincode = explode(',',$post_data['pincode']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `implode()` instead of `explode()`. It should be:

```
$explode_pincode = explode(',',$post_data['pincode']);
```

Comment: if i use explode it says     explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: Then $post_data['pincode'] seems to be already an array, try 
`$explode_pincode = $post_data['pincode'];`

Comment: Thats what i did     $explode_pincode = explode(',',$post_data['pincode']);  but still same error

Comment: How...Plz am new into php